# Gradle - Error Copying Files To Project Root

Tags: gradle

I’m getting the following error whenever I attempt to use a Copy task to copy a file into the root of a project (the same folder I’m running gradle from):

> Failed to create MD5 hash for file content.

I thought this was related to the artifacts I was pulling from Artifactory, but that seems to be unrelated. I was able to get the same results with a minimal script.

Is there something obviously wrong with what I’m doing, or does Gradle intentionally disallow such things?

> ```
> task fails(type:Copy) {
>     from 'build/someFile.txt'
>     into new File('.').absolutePath
> }
>
> task works(type:Copy) {
>     from 'build/someFile.txt'
>     into new File('.').absolutePath + '/output'
> }
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short Answer:** Don't copy into the project directory, you are best to use `into "$buildDir/someFolder"` so that the folder is isolated to this single task, and also so that it will be cleaned by `gradle clean`

**Long Answer:** At it's core, Gradle has the concept of an "UP-TO-DATE" check for every single task. If Gradle sees that nothing has changed since last time a task was executed it will use the old result instead of executing again.

UP-TO-DATE checking is implemented by taking a "hash" of the task inputs and task outputs. Since you are using `into '.'` that means that the entire contents of the project directory is considered a task output (bad)

Gradle uses the `.gradle` folder for temp files (eg task hashes) It's likely some of these files are locked for writing as Gradle is trying to also read the same files (to calculate the "hash" of the task outputs) causing the error you are seeing

*** EDIT ***

If you need to copy into the project directory for legacy reasons, you might use [Project.copy(...)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#copy(groovy.lang.Closure)) directly instead of a `Copy` task. You could manually manage the task inputs/outputs in this case

Eg

```
task customCopy {
    inputs.file "$buildDir/someFile.txt"
    outputs.file 'someFile.txt'
    doLast {
        copy {
            from "$buildDir/someFile.txt"
            into '.'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Just to clarify, this is a legacy app (12+ years old), so I'm trying to preserve the existing directory structure while moving a bunch of binaries into Artifactory and using Gradle to manage them.

Comment: Based on what you'd said, I've simply changed my task to do everything in sub-folders, and then xcopy them to the project root, and that will work for me needs.

Comment: xcopy won't be necessary and would also make your build platform dependent, see my update which uses [Project.copy(...)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#copy(groovy.lang.Closure)) instead of a `Copy` task and manually manages task inputs/outputs. Note that the `Copy` task is simply a convenience wrapper around `Project.copy(...)` which auto manages task inputs/outputs

Answer (score 0):

Can you believe it, the following works

```
task myCopy(type: Copy) {
    from "$rootDir/app1/src/main/resources/db"
    into "$rootDir/app2/src/test/resources/db"
}
test.dependsOn myCopy
```

and the following doesn't

```
task myCopy(type: Copy) {
    from '$rootDir/app1/src/main/resources'
    into '$rootDir/app2/src/test/resources'
}
test.dependsOn myCopy
```